# Converting object to int to perform aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, object, int

I have a dataframe called "modified_df".I have a variable that I am trying to aggregate, 'age' (trying to calculate things like mean). Currently, the datatype is showing as "object," which is why I am not able to aggregate it. I have cleaned through it, and everything seems to be an integer, but there is a chance I missed something.

I tried running this code

```
modified_df['Age'] = modified_df['Age'].astype('int')
```

I have attached the error message along with what "Age" looks like

[image]
[image]

Comment: The error tells you _exactly_ what the issue is. At some point in your column you have an age that is not a number, but rather just a space.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there are some values in the "Age" column which are not converting to `int` like mentioned. Try using `value_counts()` to and explore the column, or drop non-`int` columns. Try doing:

```py
modified_df['Age'] = modified_df['Age'].astype('int',errors='ignore')
```

See the `astype()` documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can try two different things.

Option 1: (converts to a float instead. This might not work, but will rule out if you have any ages that have any values that can't be an int, but can be a float.)

```
modified_df['Age'] = modified_df['Age'].astype('float')
```

Option 2: (ignores whatever is causing the error and returns original value)

```
modified_df['Age'] = modified_df['Age'].astype('int',errors = 'ignore')
```